# How to convert a PHP date string to another format

Tags: php, datetime

I've a string like "2013-05-07"
and I want to convert it in "7 May 2013" via any functional way (if available) or in short method as possible

Answer (score 6):

```
$dt = new DateTime('2013-05-07');
echo $dt->format('j F Y');
```

As of PHP 5.4

```
echo (new DateTime('2013-05-07'))->format('j F Y');
```

[PHP Date Format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 3):

```
echo date('j F Y', strtotime("2013-05-07"));
```